# Parse xml file with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

Is it possible to parse `xml` file which is located in the same directory of the specified `js` file?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 1):

sure, why not? There are many libraries on Github.com like 
https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xls

https://github.com/jindw/xmldom
https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js